# Editing Site Meta Data in Gatsby-Config.JS from a Headless CMS (like Strapi)

Tags: gatsby, strapi

Is it possible to edit the `siteMetaData` in the `gatsby-config.js` file from within a headless cms like Strapi?  I would like to give my client the ability to edit that information and not have to hard-code it myself.

If so, how could I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I am using Contentful and what I ended doing is to create a custom content-type "config" with all configuration options I want (similar to siteMeta) and I read it using graphQL wherever I want to use options from there. It's not exactly what you are looking for but, at least, may work as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this. Check the gatsby build sequence here:[gatsby build sequence](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-lifecycle-apis/#build-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to do this by creating a custom field and querying that custom field at build time.

- For Strapi see :
  https://strapi.io/documentation/user-docs/latest/content-types-builder/configuring-fields-content-type.html
- For Contentful see :
  https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/field-editors/
- For Prismic see : https://prismic.io/docs/core-concepts/fields